# Flash player 10 - full screen mode and keyboard

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, internet-explorer, keyboard, fullscreen

I am writing Flash app (Flash Player 10, AS 3.0) that is full screen capable. I got that part sorted (`allowFullscreen=true`, `stage.displayState`).

I would like to give users ability to tab through the items there and activate them using space (`MouseEvent.CLICK` ;-). I know that any keyboard actions are blocked in full screen mode. [This Adobe's devnet page](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer10_security_changes_03.html#head5) suggests that starting from Flash Player 10 some keys (tab, space, arrows) are allowed in full screen mode.

That checks out in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari... but not IE (IE6 at least). IE6 is simply oblivious of the keyboard. Nothing works: tab, space... except for Esc of course ;-)

Am I missing something?
What might be wrong?
May my testing on localhost affect this?

Comment: I don't want to state the obvious, but you do have the correct Flash Player version installed for IE6?

Comment: Yes, I do :) In IE I have version 10,0,22,87 installed, debug player ActiveX version to be exact.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. But I would check with IE7 & 8 before worying to much.

Comment: I tried IE6 and IE7 on few computers, both XP and Vista - doesn't work. I don't have access to IE8 so can't try.  
Probably back2dos and Lillemanden are correct - a bug, but had no luck finding any official Adobe's info on this. Will try to dig a while more...

Comment: Yesterday I tried uninstalling FP and installing from scratch, both Release and Debug versions of FP 10,0,22,87 Release and Debug ActiveX versions. No change - still does not work. I could not find any official info, or even other tbh, so I filed a bug report (http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-2159) to Adobe. We'll see.

Comment: Well, as you can see in the Jira link my previous comment - Adobe guys said that "This is a security restriction and not a bug. We do not allow for text input in full screen mode.". End of story - not a bug - issue closed...  
But then: why do they give the devnet article about partially lifting the keyboard restriction? And secondly why don't they consider Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari plugin as bugged because there it allows keyboard access in full screen mode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is a bug, that comes from the browser ... i've seen multiple discussions about it, one at flashhilfe.de (probably won't help you guys), where there was a test swiff embedded on some page, and everyone tried ... on my computer even firefox and opera failed completely ...

i'm afraid, you probably can't do anything about ...

just a little side note though: from the user's point of view, it is always the best, to make your apps dynamically scalable, so the user decides which size he prefers ... many people are disturbed by apps creating pop ups or resizing browser windows ...

greetz

back2dos

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking at this for a video player, the keys work fine for player 10,1,53,64 (Debug player) in FF3.6.6, cant get it to work in IE7, the tab key won't work in this either.

If you have a KeyboardEvent on the stage and listen for the key presses then you will see that they fire in full screen mode.

The `MouseEvent.CLICK` doesn't fire when you press Space when a button has focus so the way i got buttons to fire was to ass a KEY_DOWN listener to the stage, do a switch on `stage.focus` and call a function. i.e.

```
this.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, _keyUp); 

private function _keyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
{ 
   if(this.stage.displayState != StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN) return;
   switch(this.stage.focus) 
   { 
      case myButtonInstance: 
         //call function here 
      break; 
   } 
}
```

Hope this helps.